# Error accessing point data in boost::geometry polygon

Tags: c++, boost, boost-geometry

I am trying to iterate through the points in a boost polygon to perform an operation on them. To show a simplified version of my problem:

```
#include <boost/geometry.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/geometries/point_xy.hpp>

typedef boost::geometry::model::d2::point_xy<double> point_type;
typedef boost::geometry::model::polygon<point_type> polygon;

int main()
{
    polygon polygonTest;
    boost::geometry::read_wkt("POLYGON((-2 2, 2 2, 2 -2, -2 -2, -2 2))", polygonTest);

    for (point_type point : boost::geometry::exterior_ring(polygonTest))
    {
        double xCoord = point.x;
    }


    return 0;
}
```

I receive the following error:

```
'boost::geometry::model::d2::point_xy<double,boost::geometry::cs::cartesian>::x': function call missing argument list; use '&boost::geometry::model::d2::point_xy<double,boost::geometry::cs::cartesian>::x' to create a pointer to member
```

What am I overlooking to resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a *member function* `x`. But you forgot to call it:

```
    double xCoord = point.x();
```

See below for working sampel

> **Q.** What am I overlooking

You're overlooking the information in the error message.

- GCC: `error: cannot resolve overloaded function ‘x’ based on conversion to type ‘double’`

  It's telling you you're assigning a function `x` to a double...
- Clang: `error: reference to non-static member function must be called; did you mean to call it with no arguments?`

  It even goes on to list the overloads that you could want

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6e3b23664946d674)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/geometry.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/geometries/point_xy.hpp>

typedef boost::geometry::model::d2::point_xy<double> point_type;
typedef boost::geometry::model::polygon<point_type> polygon;

int main() {
    polygon polygonTest;
    boost::geometry::read_wkt("POLYGON((-2 2, 2 2, 2 -2, -2 -2, -2 2))", polygonTest);

    for (point_type point : boost::geometry::exterior_ring(polygonTest)) {
        double xCoord = point.x();
    }
}
```

Comment: Ugh. Thanks. I figured it was a stupid oversight. I was using VS, so those errors didn't show. Only the message above.

Comment: @JayDoe ... erm yeah that was as clear as the Clang message, actually :)